# Joint density of linearly transformed random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, density-function

A random vector (X, Y) is normally distributed with the following joint density:

$$
f^{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-5
   \text{x$$}{}^2-2
   \text{x$$}
   \text{y$$}-\text{y$$}{}
   ^2\right)}}{\pi }
$$

I need to calculate the joint density

$$ f^{U,V} $$

where

$$
U = X + Y
$$

and

$$
V = 2X
$$

Am I not mistaken that the location of my new distribution is going to be the following vector?

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbb{E} [X + Y]\\ \mathbb{E} [2X] \end{bmatrix}
$$

I've calculated the marginal pdfs for x and y:

$$
f^{X}(x,y) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} e^{-2x^2}
$$
$$
f^{Y}(x,y) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{5 \pi }} e^{-\frac{2 y^2}{5}}
$$

and obtained the expected values for x and y:
$$
\mathbb{E} [X] = \int_{}^{} x * f^{X}(x,y) dx = 0
$$

$$
\mathbb{E} [Y] = \int_{}^{} y * f^{Y}(x,y) dy = 0
$$

Now since x and y are normally distributed the location of x + y is going to be 0 as well.

Does it make any sense? How do I get the covariance matrix? 
Thanks a lot for any hints!

Comment: Why don't you just solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ and substitute in $f^{X,Y}(x(u,v), y(u,v))$ and use the determinant of the Jacobian of the transformation to normalize it (or directly normalize it, since the Jacobian determinant is constant).

Comment: @stochastic Thanks a lot, I was able to solve it following your advice. I posted the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @stochastic's comment, I was able to figure it out. This is how it goes:

$$
f^{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(-5
   \text{x$$}{}^2-2
   \text{x$$}
   \text{y$$}-\text{y$$}{}
   ^2\right)}}{\pi }
$$

$$
U = X + Y
$$

$$
V = 2X
$$

Our transformation function looks then like this:

$$
T(\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
         \end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}
           u \\
           v \\
         \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           x + y \\
           2x \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

We need its inverse:

$$
T^{-1}(\begin{bmatrix}
           x \\
           y \\
         \end{bmatrix}) = T(\begin{bmatrix}
           \frac{1}{2}v \\
           u - \frac{1}{2}v \\
         \end{bmatrix}) 
$$

and the jacobian:

$$
DT^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 & \frac{1}{2}\\
           1 & -\frac{1}{2} \\
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

The determinant of said jacobian is:

$$
|DT^{-1}| = -\frac{1}{2}
$$

From here we're ready to obtain the transformed joint density by substituting for u and v, and normalizing by the absolute value of the jacobian:
$$
f^{U,V}(u,v) = f^{X,Y}(\frac{1}{2}v,  u - \frac{1}{2}v) * |-\frac{1}{2}| = \frac{1}{\pi} e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2} -\frac{v^{2}}{2} }
$$